# Laravel route /users/id or /users/username to return users.show

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I would like to be able to accept either a 40-character string ID `/users/{id}` or the user's username `/users/{username}` and then return the `users.show` view.

1. Is this possible?
2. Where would the checks go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found another solution to this. I don't know which is better though. Hopefully the community can vote...

Within my **UsersController.php** I have:

```
public function show($id_or_username)
    {
        $user = User::where('id' , '=', $id_or_username)->orWhere('username', $id_or_username)->firstOrFail();
        return View::make('users.show', compact('user'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Implicit Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#implicit-binding)**

For those who are looking for the Laravel 5.3+ answer:

Jeffery Way talked about this in one of his [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/); not sure which one though.

Basically, you can pass the username through a route like this:

```
// you will need to set this up so the route ('/user/{user}')
// matches the Model you're binding to -> App\<User>
// ('/user/{username}') will not work 

Route::get('/user/{user}', function(App\User $user){
    // $user should now be App\User
    return view('user.show', compact('user'));

    // access the user in the 'user.show' view
    // like: $user->username
});
```

However, to make this work, you need to add this to the User class:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Otherwise this would only work if you passed the id of the user in place of the username -> /user/1

Comment: The moment you set **getRouteKeyName** you won't be able to navigate by ID, only username. OP's question specifies they want to be able to route by both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this with [Explicit Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding).

To do this:

1. **Use the Route::bind method to specify custom binding logic**

   To do this  add the following code to the **boot** method of the **RouteServiceProvider** class.

   ```
   Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
       return \App\User::where('id', $value)->orWhere('username', $value)->first();
   });
   ```
2. **Set up your route for Route Model Binding**

   ```
   Route::get('/{user}', 'UserController@show');
   ```
3. **Modify your controller to accept the bound model**

   ```
   public function show(User $user)
   {
       echo $user;
   }
   ```

There's a couple of advantages here over the other answers:

- Using the route model binding rather than having the finding logic within your **show** method will make it more reusable if you want to apply the same logic to different requests.
- No need for a separate **showByUserName** and **showByUserID** method.
- Using **getRouteKeyName** will only work for either ID or username, you can't use it to specify multiple keys.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to match certain patterns, I use the `Route::pattern()` method in the top of my **routes.php** file. For example:

```
Route::pattern('userid', '[0-9]{40}');
Route::pattern('username', '[a-zA-Z0-9]+');
```

You can easily adapt that to use your own regular expression to match whatever you need and then you just create two routes to match the requests:

```
Route::get('/users/{userid}', 'UserController@showByUserID');
Route::get('/users/{username}, 'UserController@showByUserName');
```

Those two controller methods would get the user differently, but both would call the same view file and pass in the user.